# The function PL/SQL doesn't return any value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the next `PL/SQL` code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION NUMBER_PLATES (name VARCHAR2)
RETURN INT
IS

    num_plates INT;

BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO num_plates
    FROM plate p, detail_ped dt
    WHERE dt.plate = p.cod_plate AND p.name = name;

    RETURN (num_plates);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');

END NUMBER_PLATES;
```

The next is execute the function into SQL Commands:

```
DECLARE a INT;
BEGIN
    a := NUMBER_PLATES('chicken');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
END;
```

But the function returns me 0 when really is 3.

What am I doing wrong?

If I execute my `SQL` sentence returns 3:

```
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM plate p, detail_ped dt
    WHERE dt.plate = p.cod_plate AND p.name = 'chicken';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename parameter name to avoid name collision:

```
create or replace FUNCTION NUMBER_PLATES (p_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN INT
IS
    num_plates INT;
BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO num_plates
    FROM plate p
    JOIN detail_ped dt                 -- proper JOIN syntax
      ON dt.plate = p.cod_plate
    WHERE p.name = p_name;

    RETURN (num_plates);
-- exception is dead code, COUNT(*) will return 0 if no records found
-- EXCEPTION
--    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
--    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
END NUMBER_PLATES;
/
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f26606167db43945dd42576c7e96b8c8)**